# Why do the Greens have no group in PACE?

Tags: parliament, europe

In the [Parliamentary Assembly of the Council of Europe (PACE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_Assembly_of_the_Council_of_Europe), there are five political groups: socialist/communist (Unified European Left), social-democratic (called Socialist), liberal (Alliance of Liberals and Democrats for Europe), conservative (European Conservatives Group), and christian-democrat (European People's Party).  The Greens (such as unified in the European Green Party) do not have their own group.  According to [unsourced Wikipedia statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_Group), they join either the social-democrats or the liberals.

Why is there no Green group in PACE?

Comment: (+1) A wild guess, with no evidence: The delegations are very small, typically 4-7, at most 18 and they are named by their national parliaments, not elected with some sort of proportional representation. Even if there is a requirement to send members of both the opposition and the ruling party, that's two levels of “rounding” that could easily squeeze out smaller political parties and make the system much less favourable than that of the European Parliament. Are there even 20 Green members from at least 6 states?

Comment: Too small could certainly be the answer.  In the EU parliament they're about as large as the socialist/communist group, but perhaps non-EU member states send relatively more socialist/communist members than green members, green parties being more successful in western than in eastern Europe...

Comment: I'm guessing being able to be a swing vote is pretty sweet. There are many examples of outsize influence (in terms of getting what they want) of a party which is flexible about joining coalitions.

Comment: @DVK I'm not sure if PACE is quite relevant enough for such politicking to occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some more digging and here is what I could find.

The bit about Greens sitting in different groups can be verified on the official website. For example, the German Green Party currently sends two representatives to the assembly: [Luise Amtsberg](http://www.assembly.coe.int/nw/xml/AssemblyList/MP-Details-EN.asp?MemberID=7217) (Socialist Group) and [Marieluise Beck](http://www.assembly.coe.int/nw/xml/AssemblyList/MP-Details-EN.asp?MemberID=5646) (Alliance of Liberals and Democrats for Europe) plus two substitutes.

Now, as to why they don't have their own group, it would seem that the way members are selected is much less favourable to small parties than the procedure used for the European Parliament. The delegations are very small and should reflect the composition of their respective national parliaments.

If the national elections do not use proportional representation, a party with a 10-15% share of the vote can be (almost) entirely squeezed out of the national parliament, and therefore of the delegation to the PACE (case of the Front National in France).

(There is also a potential feedback effect in that voters know that the elections to the European Parliament are a good occasion to show their support for small fringe parties which have no shot in regular parliamentary elections.)

Even if the parliamentary elections use proportional representation, rounding effects could limit the number of representatives, especially among the smallest delegations (although it could also occasionally increase it, as with Bündnis 90/Die Grünen, which gathered 8.4% of the votes in the last federal elections, 10% of the seats in the Bundestag and over 11% of the delegation to the PACE).

To test this theory, I tallied the number of representatives who belong to a party that is a member of [The Greens–European Free Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Greens%E2%80%93European_Free_Alliance) group in the European Parliament:

- Austria, Die Grünen – Die Grüne Alternative, 3 MEP, 1 representative
- Belgium, Ecolo and Groen, 2 MEP, no representative (but one substitute)
- Croatia, Održivi razvoj Hrvatske, 1 MEP, no representative
- Denmark, Socialistisk Folkeparti, 1 MEP, 1 representative
- Estonia, one independent MEP seating with the Greens, no green representative
- Finland, Vihreä liitto/Gröna Förbundet, 1 MEP, no representative (but one substitute)
- France, Europe Écologie – Les Verts, 6 MEP, 1 representative
- Germany, Bündnis 90/Die Grünen, 11 MEP (plus one MEP from the Piratenpartei Deutschland), 2 representatives
- Hungary, Lehet Más a Politika, 1 MEP, no representative (but one substitute)
- Latvia, Latvijas Krievu savienība/Русский союз Латвии (not mainly a green party as far as I can tell and not a member of the European Green Party but its MEP does seat in the same group), 1 MEP, no representative (there is also a MEP and a representative from the Union of Green and Farmers Parliamentary Group)
- Lithuania, Lietuvos valstiečių ir žaliųjų sąjunga (also more an agrarian party than a green party), 1 MEP, no representative
- Luxembourg, Déi Gréng, 1 MEP, no representative
- Netherlands, GroenLinks, 2 MEP, no representative (but one substitute)
- Spain, Esquerra Republicana de Catalunya, Iniciativa per Catalunya Verds and Bloc Nacionalista Valencià, 4 MEP, no representative
- Slovenia, Verjamem, 1 MEP, no representative
- Sweden, Miljöpartiet de Gröna, 2 MEP, no representative
- United Kingdom, Green Party of England and Wales, Scottish National Party and Plaid Cymru – Party of Wales, 6 MEP, no representative

This does not count green parties in non-EU states like Switzerland but it should be clear that the total (5 representatives, 6 substitutes) is well under the threshold of 20 members to form a group.